# Convert 12 hr time to 24 hr format in Ruby

Tags: ruby, datetime, date

How do I convert "11am" and "10pm" into "11:00" and "22:00"? Is there a simple way using the date and time classes?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I would first parse the string with `Time#strptime` and then output it with `Time#strftime`. This ensures a strict check with your original format as well.

```
require 'time'
Time.strptime("10pm", "%I%P").strftime("%H:%M")
=> "22:00"
```

Comment: +1 for the "require 'time'", which also adds a parse method to the Time class (if strictness is not desirable).

Answer (score 13):

The Time class has no parse method, but DateTime has.

```
require 'date'
DateTime.parse("11pm").strftime("%H:%M") #=> "23:00"
```

Comment: Perfect! I erroneously did DateTime.parse("11pm").to_time.strftime("%H:%M") before. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your question is unclear, but it sounds like you have a string "10pm", and you need to (1) capture it as a Time, and (2) represent that Time in 24-hour format. I would do it like this. First, `gem install chronic`, then, write a script like this:

```
require 'chronic'
t = Chronic.parse('10pm')
p t.strftime("%H:%M")
```

Returns "22:00"

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you want 11am and 10pm and then the ability to 11:00 and 22:00 or do you want how to show 11:00 and 22:00 instead of 11am and 10pm?

if its the second question here:

`%H -   Hour of the day, 24-hour clock (00 to 23).`

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w
time = Time.new

puts time.to_s
puts time.ctime
puts time.localtime
puts time.strftime("%H:%M")
```

if its the first question tell:

`%I Hour of the day, 12-hour clock (01 to 12).`

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby -w
time = Time.new
timeSwitch = 1

if (timeSwitch == 1)
    puts time.strftime("%H:%M")
else 
    puts time.strftime("%I:%M")
end
```

Sorry about that had perl and ruby mixed up on syntax

Comment: I've seen the %H and %I flags in strftime(). I'm not trying to format the current time. I have a string with '10pm' and I would like to convert it to '22:00'. Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Just do time_string + 12 = convertedTime
so `time = 10 puts time + 12 = 22`