# Convert 12-hour time to 24-hour time with a regex

Tags: ruby, regex, string, time

I have a bunch of strings with opening hours in this format:

```
Mon-Fri: AM7:00-PM8:00\nSat-Sun: AM8:00-PM6:00
```

I can deal with the "AM" part by just removing it, but I'd like to convert the PM by

- Removing "PM"
- Adding 12 to the number before the ":"
- Taking care of the fact that PM is sometimes double-digits (e.g. PM11:00)

There can be zero or more PM times in the string.

I'm not sure how to manipulate the time as a number. I've gotten this far:

```
opening_hours.sub! /PM([\d]?[\d]):/, "***\1***"
```

Which outputs things like this:

```
AM7:15-***\u0001***00
```

The '\u0001` may be due to Japanese characters in the string.

Comment: This is not to be done with regex alone. You can only do this by using regex to match, and provide a replacement function to do the replacement based on the text matched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that `String#gsub` accepts a block. Something like this will do for you?

```
s = "Mon-Fri: AM7:00-PM8:00\nSat-Sun: AM8:00-PM11:00"

s2 = s.gsub('AM', '').gsub(/PM(\d+)/) do |match|
  (match.gsub('PM', '').to_i + 12).to_s
end

s2 # => "Mon-Fri: 7:00-20:00\nSat-Sun: 8:00-23:00"
```

Comment: What about `AM12:00` and `PM12:00`?

Comment: Excellent, this works perfectly, thanks! @maerics In my case at least, AM12:00 can be left as is, and there are no PM12:00s, only a single PM0:00 (which I'll do by hand)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this question, ruby has a class called datatime.

[Convert 12 hr time to 24 hr format in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422534/convert-12-hr-time-to-24-hr-format-in-ruby)